# How to get tracking info using tracking Number

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, shipment-tracking

I want get tracking info, which is used in `popup.phtml`.
In `trackingcontroller.php` tracking info load by hash.

```
 $shippingInfoModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/info')->loadByHash($this->getRequest()->getParam('hash'));
```

How to load tracking info using tracking number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways would be to extend the shipping/info model with your own extension, add a method to load it from tracking number without the hash. You can also look at `Mage_Shipping_Helper_Data::decodeTrackingHash()` and see how to build the hash yourself.

I believe the intent behind the hash is to stop people from fishing for shipping info on orders/shippments that are not related to them.

Comment: @Marius how to add custom tracking info, i have developed one custom shipping method, what are the methods used to add the tracking information

Comment: if your shipping carrier supports tracking, you can check how it's done for DHL or UPS and implement something similar.